# how to change the height of a div on mouseover with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate, delay

I am trying to increase the height of a div when hovering over links with jquery.
the height of the div should stay the same when transitioning between these links and should have a delay when first hovering over a link.
I also need the height increase to transit/animate from 0px tall to 400px tall.
this is the code that I am currently using, but it doesn't work??

```
 $(document).on("mouseenter", ".navDropLink", function() {
     console.log("MOUSEENTER");
     tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');
     tab_id_this = $(this).attr('id');
     setTimeoutConst = setTimeout(function(){
               $("#"+tab_id).animateAuto("height", 1000); 
      }, delay);
});
$(document).on("mouseleave", ".navDropLink", function() {
    clearTimeout(setTimeoutConst );
});
```

Comment: can you add a jsfiddle?

Comment: dont really know how to... do you know of a tutorial I can follow to achieve this

Comment: i am looking to make a menu similar to the one on mashable.com

Comment: 1.Go to [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/)  2. Add your HTML in left-top box 3. Add your Javascript in left-bottom box 4. Add your CSS in right-top box. 5. If you want to use any external plugins like jQuery, then select it from the dropdown in the left panel 6. Click on the 'Run' button. If everything is ok, then you will get the result in the right-bottom box. 7. Click on the 'Save' button and share the URL

Comment: awesome thanks will do that now

Comment: I found out what my problem was whilst doing the jsfiddle ...it was positioned absolute with bottom 0px so it expanded up behind the menu instead of downso i set it to top 0px;

Answer (score 0):

```
var delay=500, setTimeoutConst;
                    var tab_id, tab_id_this;

                    $(document).on("mouseenter", "#articlesLink", function() {
                         console.log("MOUSEENTER");
                         tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');
                         tab_id_this = $(this).attr('id');
                         setTimeoutConst = setTimeout(function(){
                                   $('#navFullDropdown').stop().animate({'height': '400px'}, 500);
                          }, delay);
                    });
                    $(document).on("mouseleave", "#articlesLink", function() {
                    $('#navFullDropdown').stop().animate({'height': '0px'}, 500);
                        clearTimeout(setTimeoutConst );
                    });
```